# Dynamically add parameters to Jenkins Job dsl configuration

Tags: groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to check if a file exists(TestParams.txt). If it exists it should add parameters block in job dsl groovy script.

content of **TestParams.txt**

```
     parameters {
        booleanParam('FLAG', true)
        choiceParam('OPTION', ['option 1 (default)', 'option 2', 'option 3'])
    }
```

JenkinsFile.groovy

```
import groovy.io.FileType
def ParamFile= new File("TestParams.txt").text.readLines()
pipelineJob('Testing') {
    ParamFile
    definition {
        cps {
            script(readFileFromWorkspace('Testing'))
        }
    }
}
```

**Testing** is the file that has actual pipeline content

**ParamFile** i included inside jobdsl is not considered.